# 2 Qm's @ MQ8 one with TLS other without TLS.Connection issue

Tags: ibm-mq

I have 2 QM's

1. QM1[enabled TLS]
2. QM2[basic QM]

same client connects to both these QM's depends on functionality.

Now issue is First QM1 is enabled with TLS and connected and working fine. When trying to connect to QM2 with same client its failing to connect.

Reason is because of MQEnvironment public static class variables, and it uses same TLS values to QM2. Now i code , i disable as below , when it connect to QM2.

1. MQEnvironment.sslSocketFactory = null;
2. MQEnvironment.sslFipsRequired = false;
3. MQEnvironment.sslCipherSuite = "";

Now exception says need certificate  for QM2(which , i dont need to create)

```
AMQ9660: SSL key repository: password stash file absent or unusable.
```

Question is like which MQEnvironment. property , i can set to remove certificate value as above

Trying with

- MQEnvironment.sslCertStores = null;
- MQEnvironment.SSLKeyRepository = "";

Comment: MQEnvironment is global. Try with a property hash table.

Comment: when trying for TLS , all 'MQEnvironment' variables are set properly. Issue is like client trying to connect to NON-TLS-enabled QM(QM2), its failing because for global variable. So coded like removing all unwanted values 1. 2. 3. as above. Tell me , what is the better way of code ? in this scenario?

Comment: Try using a property hash table instead of using MQEnvironment.

Comment: MQEnvironment.sslCertStores = null; resolved issue . Now able to connect to both QM's properly .could you able to give code snippet for the [hash table] same as 1,2,3 + MQEnvironment.sslCertStores = null; Try to give in block , so that i can vote and give 'green tick mark'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> could you able to give code snippet for the [hash table]

You do know that there is a search bar at the top of every stackoverflow.com page.  Here are some examples that I have posted:

- [Websphere MQ issue while writing a message to queue from java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38563828/websphere-mq-issue-while-writing-a-message-to-queue-from-java-program/38594676#38594676)
- [2538 - MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42227367/2538-mqrc-host-not-available/42233408#42233408)
- [Java program to connect WMQ with User Id instead of channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34628283/java-program-to-connect-wmq-with-user-id-instead-of-channel/34642355#34642355)